# Spoon and Espresso testing

Tags: android, android-testing, ui-testing, android-espresso, spoon

So, I have a test that goes through my whole application. Now, I want to take a picture of everything. Since it has 2 activities and numerous fragments in it, I can't make it work since it only takes first fragment of every activity.

How can I achieve that I take picture of every fragment?

```
   @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class HearthBeatUITest {

    private final int MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT = 700;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<IntroActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(IntroActivity.class);
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mLoginActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

    @Test
    /**
     * Testing all the screens on the application if they are actually there
     */
    public void startTest() {
        Session.clear();
        Spoon.screenshot(mActivityRule.getActivity(), "initial_state");
        threadSleep(MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT);
        onView(withId(R.id.button_register)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
        threadSleep(MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT);
        Spoon.screenshot(mLoginActivityRule.getActivity(), "register_intro");
        onView(withId(R.id.register_with_email)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
        threadSleep(MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT);
        Spoon.screenshot(mLoginActivityRule.getActivity(), "register_detailed");
        onView(withId(R.id.image_left_button)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
        threadSleep(MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT);
        Spoon.screenshot(mLoginActivityRule.getActivity(), "register_intro");
        onView(withId(R.id.image_left_button)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
        threadSleep(MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT);
        Spoon.screenshot(mActivityRule.getActivity(), "initial_state");
        onView(withId(R.id.button_signin)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
        threadSleep(MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT);
        Spoon.screenshot(mLoginActivityRule.getActivity(), "login_intro");
        onView(withId(R.id.sign_in_emal)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
        threadSleep(MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT);
        Spoon.screenshot(mLoginActivityRule.getActivity(), "login_detailed");
    }

}
```

Comment: Does your fragments have animations? remove animations and turn off animations in dev settings as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you will need only one rule:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class HearthBeatUITest {

    private final int MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT = 300;
    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<IntroActivity> mActivityRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(IntroActivity.class);
    private Activity currentActivity;
}
```

now, when you need context for creating screenshots, you will call this method:

```
   private Activity getActivityInstance() {
        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Collection resumedActivities = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(RESUMED);
                if (resumedActivities.iterator().hasNext()) {
                    currentActivity = (Activity) resumedActivities.iterator().next();
                }
            }
        });

        return currentActivity;
    }
```

It will get you current activity and you will be able to take screenshots. Just fyi, you can't take screenshot of dialogs.